# A Taylor Expansion before Taylor

Tags: taylor-expansion, math-history

Taylor expansion was introduced in its currently well known form by [Brook Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brook_Taylor). Though the concept as [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) says, has been formulated by [James Gregory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gregory_%28mathematician%29). Among his other works, Gregory established $$\theta = \tan \theta - \frac13 \tan^3 \theta + \frac15 \tan^5 \theta - \ldots$$
which can easily be established when $|\tan \theta|<1$.

I was now thinking, how did Gregory thought of this problem? what did he know back then? I will be happy with any historical note/book. Many thanks.

Comment: I forget his name, but there was an Indian mathematician that developed several series expansions associated with trigonometric functions before Newton was born. I'm not sure who has precedence, but I always wondered what principles he used to derive them. I look forward to seeing a good answer to your question.

Comment: @Spencer It's probably Madhava of Sangamagrama (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama).

Comment: This may be better suited for [hsm.se]. What do you think, Math-fun?